# A problem of similarity related to Erdös-Mordell Theorem

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

I have found a problem in a book of H. S. Coxeter. As a hint, he says that the triangles $OPB$ anb $PRQ$ are similar, but I don´t know why. I have dealing with angles for a while, but I can`t seee the way to involve the segment $PQ$.

[image]

I'll describe the figure more precisely. Take a triangle $ABC$ and any point $O$ inside it. $OP$ and $OQ$ are perpendicular to sides $AB$ and $BC$, respectively. $PR$ is also perpendicular to $BC$. So the problem is proving that $\angle PBO=\angle RPQ$.

Any ideas?

*Notes:*

- Please avoid trigonometry and Cartesian plane. It is a problem of classic geometry.
- In the figure, $P$, $Q$ and $R$ lie on the sides, but they can be outside the triangle.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it trivially follows from the fact that $OP$ and $OQ$ are perpendiculars to $AB$ and $BC$, respectively. That is, the quadrilateral $OPBQ$ is cyclic so:
$$\angle PBO = \frac\pi 2 - \angle POB = \frac\pi 2 - \angle PQB = \angle RPQ.$$

Comment: @ajotatxe yes. More generally,  a quadrilateral is cyclic if and only if its opposite angles add up to $180^\circ.$

Comment: That's it, thank you, I only disagree with the word 'trivially' ;) The point is that if $ABC$ and $ABD$ are right rectangles that share the hypotenuse AB, then the both triangles have the same circumcenter and then quadrilateral $ACBD$ is cyclic, isn't it?

Comment: I know, but this is not proved so far... Any way, I didn't see that 'magic' circle.